# На Мете отличается цветовое выделение ссылки, состоящей из внутристрочного кода в предпросмотре и результате

Tags: дефект, форматирование, markdown

Код в теле вопроса или ответа:

```
[пример `код` пример][2] просто строка
[пример `код` пример][3] просто строка
  [2]: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/
  [3]: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/abcdefgh
```

Предпросмотр результата при редактировании, ссылки всегда выделены красным цветом:

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Результат, посещённые ссылки серые:

[пример `код` пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/) просто строка

Не посещённые — красные

[пример `код` пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/abcdefgh) просто строка

Воспроизводится только на Мете, на основном сайте ссылки корректно подсвечиваются синим цветом.

Comment: Поначалу непривычно, потом перестаёшь обращать внимание на такую мелочь.